# What are some of the best book in mathematics for general reader?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education

I am preparing a list for my department library, consisting books of mathematics for general readers. I've included ***The men of mathematics*** by **Bell**, ***Fermat's last theorem*** by **S.Singh** , ***The man who knew infinity*** and ***The equation that couldn't be solved.*** But I need more books to add into my list. Can anyone suggest a few more, where mathematical development of certain concepts/problems or evolution is described in a lucid manner or contains mathematics which everyone can understand. Many thanks!

Comment: I've seen some pretty good popularizations on the shelves at Barnes & Noble. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I do not understand why this question has been closed. It is not asking for  "the best" mathematics book. Just for some recommendations. How is this different from asking for a book recommendation on, say, Linear Algebra?

Comment: I agree with Mathmo123: Any book recommendation will by definition be opinion-based, but this does not mean it is not useful. Such questions should be allowed.

Comment: I need to make a list so I asked here, and so far I am having good responses, so this question should be allowed. I need more suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendations

1. Taming the infinite by Ian Stewart.
2. The great mathematical problems by Ian Stewart.
3. Does God play dice by Mario Livio
4. Golden Ratio by Mario Livio

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend these books:

Journey through Genius

Dr. Euler's Fabulous Formula

Prime Obsession

The Music of the Primes

Gödel's Proof (by Ernest Nagel)

The Code Book

Answer (score 4):

Here are some examples:

- Ian Roulstone, John Norbury: *Invisible in the Storm: The Role of Mathematics in Understanding Weather*
- Vladimir Arnold: *Catastrophe Theory*
- Julian Havil: *GAMMA*
- David Harel: *Computers Ltd*
- George Szpiro: *Kepler's Conjecture*
- Malba Tahan: *The Man Who Counted: A Collection of Mathematical Adventures*.

Answer (score 3):

I've only read the first couple chapters (so far), but I really like the Springer Undergrad Texts in Mathematics book

**Mathematics and its History** by John Stillwell

Also, I don't think you can do wrong with Newton's **Philosophiae Naturalis Principia Mathematica** - 'twas the book that first roused my interest in matters physick and mathematick.

As well, I don't think one can do better than in the biography department than to walk out with Gauss's life story under his arm. **Carl Friedrich Gauss - Titan of Science** served as a most pleasant pre-bedtime adventure for a wonderful week of my life.

Answer (score 2):

*Mathematics* by David Bergamini is good.  Some of it (especially the parts about computers) is dated, but much of it is just as valid today as it ever was.